# Angularjs get file url using FileReader

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, filereader

```
element.bind('change', function () {

                var file = element[0].files[0];
                console.log(file);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var url1 = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                console.log(url1);
            });
```

I have used this in my directive. When I console file it displays file name, last modified date etc. But when I console url1 it is showing undefined. How can I get image url using file reader. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check reader object instead of assigning it to a variable:

```
element.bind('change', function () {
    var file = element[0].files[0];
    console.log(file);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    console.dir(reader);
    });
```

Result:

```
FileReader    error    :    null
onabort    :    null
onerror    :    null
onload    :    ƒ (e)
onloadend    :    null
onloadstart    :    null
onprogress    :    null
readyState    :    2
result    :    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K[...]
```

Comment: JSFiddle, check it again, its not the same... clue: two last lines

Comment: Thank you. Can you know the reason why it hasn't worked when I set the result to url1? Knowing the reason will be very helpful.

Comment: I think that it has something to do with the onload function, which is asynchronous. If you check console you'll see that it takes a while to appear the result so using `reader.onload = function(){[Here you'll have the value]);};`